# Adjust pdfpagewidth automatically based on very large table content

Tags: geometry, paper-size, page, size, resize

I have one or more very large tables that are created by code outside.

I want to place them on one very large page.
What I am doing is currently:

```
\clearpage
\eject \pdfpagewidth=50cm \pdfpageheight=40cm
\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{table}[!ht]
\centering
\begin{minipage}{0.8\pdfpagewidth}
...
```

Now the problem is this needs to be done manually.
How can I scale up this single page automatically so it fits the content of a table-like environment onto a single page?

Comment: I cannot change the document class in case this becomes relevant.

Comment: Use the standalone class to create a pdf with just the table and then include this page in your other document?

Comment: Thank you for the idea with standalone for a more general case it does work. But in my case I cannot get it to work with my main document class to display references correctly.